# php using mpdf generates pdf according to the last data

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, mpdf

I am using mpdf with codeigniter for my project, unfortunately I face a problem and couldn't fix it up to now. I want to generate many pdf files, when I print_r the array of forms or print the value of each html data that is converted to the pdf, the result is fine. However when I generate the pdfs, all of the pdfs are generated based on the first pdf's data. I am appreciated who help me.Thank you.

```
public function mfiles($mforms,$form_name){ 
        //print_r($mforms); this results fine
        $write_data="" ;
        foreach ($mforms as $key=>$res){
            foreach ($res as $key_name) {
                foreach($key_name as $v){
                    $value=(object)$v;
                    $i=$i+1;
                    $write_data .= $i.'.'.$value->question.'('.$value->score.')'."<br/>a)".$value->choice1."<br/>b)".$value->choice2."<br/>c)".$value->choice3."<br/>d)".$value->choice4."<br/><br/>";
                }
            }
            $this->create_mfiles($write_data,$form_name,++$key);
        }
}
public function create_mfiles($mfile,$form_name,$f){
        //here when I run print $mfile;, it also prints the correct data
        $this->load->library('m_pdf');
        $file2='application'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'exam_forms'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$form_name.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$form_name.$f.'.pdf';
        $t=new m_pdf();
        $t->pdf->WriteHTML($mfiles);
        $t->pdf->Output($file2, "F");
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find any solution up to now

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `$write_data="";` after the first `foreach`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10705642)

Comment: @mjp66. This might be the solution. Since the op is using `$write_data .=`, the variable might need some cleaning. What this answer needs is some explanation and a response from the OP. ^^